# How to delete my contact using a dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, alert, contacts, android-contacts

What I'm trying here is I want to long press the number that I select and it will pop-up an alert dialog that ask me to delete. If I press Ok it will be deleted. I'm new here, I'm new in android I just want it know if it's possible to do that. If yes, where do I start. Can you show me a sample code?

Here's my code in extracting my contacts to my app:

```
public void getNumber(ContentResolver cr) {
    Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        System.out.println(name+"\n"+phoneNumber);
        aa.add(name);
        aa.add(phoneNumber);
    }

    phones.close();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,aa);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this directly beneath where you have set the adapter at lv.setAdapter(adapter);

```
lv.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this)
        .setMessage(
                getString(R.string.yourMsg))
        .setPositiveButton(
                "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(
                            DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }).show();
        return false;
    }
});
```